# How to change the fontImage color while click on it in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

We developed app using Codename one in that We have a requirement to change the color of the FontImage.Material_Icons while click on it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a `Button` e.g.

```
Button btn = new Button("My Button");
btn.setIcon(myFontIcon);
```

Then you can use the `setPressedIcon()` method to provide an alternate icon to be shown while the button is pressed.  So you would have:

```
Button btn = new Button("My Button");
btn.setIcon(myFontIcon);
btn.setPressedIcon(myAlternateColorFontIcon);
```